# RESTful WebService with callback option

Tags: wcf, http, rest, wcf-binding

I am trying to create a WCF RESTful WebService that has a WebGet-Attribute for some operations, so i can show their results/updates in browser (here, am using HttpBinding). But I also want to notify other clients about these results/updates using Callback. I know that for this wsDualHttpBinding is needed. My question is, can i still request/access my operations in browser, or this is not supported in wsDualHttpBinding. If yes plz post an example or refer to a tutorial

thanks in  advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this scenario, I'd recomend you to check some "websocket" solutions, like node.js, signalR,...

For example: http://martinsikora.com/nodejs-and-websocket-simple-chat-tutorial

Also, from this post: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/89dfefb8-7fa9-4bb0-8295-03447578a59d/

. . . callback functionality (duplex communication) is available only for SOAP services.